# How to draw multiple Venn Diagrams using jVenn Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I am working on an application and I need to draw multiple Venn Diagrams. I went for jVenn jQuery Plugin(http://bioinfo.genotoul.fr/jvenn/documentation.html). it works fine when you want to draw only 1 Venn Diagram but when you try to draw more than 1 Venn diagram it doesnt work at all. It just draws the last Venn Diagram.

DEMOS

**Drawing only 1 Venn Diagram (Works fine)**
https://jsfiddle.net/uhqqqrgh/

**Trying to draw more than 1 Venn Diagram (Not working)**
https://jsfiddle.net/uhqqqrgh/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="example">

</div>

<div id="example1">

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').jvenn({
    series: [{
        name: 'Actors',
        data: ["Marilyn Monroe", "Arnold Schwarzenegger", "Jack Nicholson", "Barbra Streisand", "Robert de Niro", "Dean Martin", "Harrison Ford"]
      }, {
        name: 'Singers',
        data: ["Freddy Mercury", "Barbra Streisand", "Dean Martin", "Ricky Martin", "Celine Dion", "Marilyn Monroe"]
      }]
  });


  $('#example1').jvenn({
    series: [{
        name: 'Models',
        data: ["Marilyn Monroe1", "Arnold Schwarzenegger", "Jack Nicholson", "Barbra Streisand", "Robert de Niro", "Dean Martin", "Harrison Ford"]
      }, {
        name: 'Directors',
        data: ["Freddy Mercury", "Barbra Streisand", "Dean Martin", "Ricky Martin", "Celine Dion", "Marilyn Monroe"]
      }]
  });
});
```

**NOTE** In demos initial jQuery is the plugin code and for the code to initiate jVenn is written at the bottom.

Comment: or plz suggest any other better plugins

Answer (score 0):

I checked this plug-in. It is working on id's internally and there is no context pass while selecting any element. That's why it always display the content inside the first container. You have to choose some other plug-in like D3.js.

May be this [link](http://www.benfrederickson.com/venn-diagrams-with-d3.js/) will help you.